# Using default None values in Python when assigning split() to a tuple

Tags: python, parsing, error-handling, null

Let's say I want to parse audio track information into two variables like this:

- `'2/15'` -> `track = 2, num_tracks = 15`
- `'7'` -> `track = 7, num_tracks = None`

What's an elegant way to do this in Python? For example:

```
track, num_tracks = track_info.split('/')
```

This works for the first format, but not for the second, raising *ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack*. So I came up with this:

```
try:
    track, num_tracks = track_info.split('/', 1)
except:
    track, num_tracks = track_info, None
```

How can this be more elegant or better?

Comment: Don't use a bare `except` though; catch specific exceptions only. You'd be amazed how many bugs could be masked by blanket `except` statements.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ```
> try:
>     track, num_tracks = track_info.split('/', 1)
> except:
>     track, num_tracks = track_info, None
> ```

Honestly, this is not a terrible solution. But you should almost never use `except:`; you should catch a specific exception.

Here is another way:

```
tracks, _, num_tracks = text.partition('/')
return int(tracks), int(num_tracks) if num_tracks else None
```

Comment: I would remove the parameter maxsplit=1 to split. If the text contains more than one '/' it is a good thing to get an error.

Answer (score 7):

You can concatenate an array with your default value.

```
track, num_tracks = (track_info.split('/', 1) + [None])[:2]
```

Answer (score 6):

This may be overly generic, but could be reused. It "pads" a sequence by making it long enough to fit the requested length, adding as many repetitions as necessary of a given padding item.

```
def right_pad(length, seq, padding_item=None):
    missing_items = length - len(seq)
    return seq + missing_items * [ padding_item]
```

If the sequence is long enough already, nothing will be added.
So the idea is to extend to 2 elements with None, if the second is not present:

```
track, num_tracks = right_pad(2, track_info.split('/'))
```